# Prevent circular references when getting result from database

Tags: c#, recursion, ef-core-2.2

If I have the following simple model:

```
    public class Company
    {
        public Guid CompanyId { get; set; }

        public ICollection<CompanyUser> Users { get; set; }
    }

    public class CompanyUser
    {
        public Guid CompanyId { get; set; }

        public Guid UserId { get; set; }

        public Company Company { get; set; }

        public User User { get; set; }
    }

    public class User
    {
        public Guid UserId { get; set; }

        public ICollection<CompanyUser> Companies { get; set; }
    }
```

To get a list of companies + their users + the user object I run the following query:

```
return await _dataContext.Companies
    .Include(m => m.Users)
    .ThenInclude(m => m.User)
    .OrderBy(m => m.Name)
    .ToListAsync();
```

The results work, but I use a mapper to map the results to a view model by going recurisvely through the model.

What happens is that the `Company` object has a reference to a list of `CompanyUser`, in each of those `CompanyUser` objects we have a `Company` which has a list of `CompanyUser` again, which just keeps repeating until we get a stack overflow.

[image]

The mapper is a very simple one:

```
var results = companies.ToViewModel<Company, CompanyViewModel>();
```

```
public static IList<TModel> ToViewModel<TEntity, TModel>(this IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
    where TEntity : class
    where TModel : class, IViewModel<TEntity>, new()
{
    return entities?.Select(entity => entity.ToViewModel<TEntity, TModel>()).ToList();
}

public static TModel ToViewModel<TEntity, TModel>(this TEntity entity)
    where TEntity : class
    where TModel : class, IViewModel<TEntity>, new()
{
    if (entity == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    var model = new TModel();
    model.ToViewModel(entity);
    return model;
}
```

```
public interface IViewModel<in TEntity>
    where TEntity : class
{
    void ToViewModel(TEntity entity);
}

public class CompanyViewModel : IViewModel<Company>
{
    public Guid CompanyId { get; set; }

    public IList<CompanyUserViewModel> Users { get; set; }

    public void ToViewModel(Company entity)
    {
        CompanyId = entity.CompanyId;
        Users = entity.Users.ToViewModel<CompanyUser, CompanyUserViewModel>();
    }
}

public class CompanyUserViewModel : IViewModel<CompanyUser>
{
    public Guid CompanyId { get; set; }

    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    public CompanyViewModel Company { get; set; }

    public UserViewModel User { get; set; }

    public void ToViewModel(CompanyUser entity)
    {
        CompanyId = entity.CompanyId;
        UserId = entity.UserId;
        Company = entity.Company.ToViewModel<Company, CompanyViewModel>();
        User = entity.User.ToViewModel<User, UserViewModel>();
    }
}

public class UserViewModel : IViewModel<User>
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    public void ToViewModel(User entity)
    {
        UserId = entity.Id;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to prevent these references to be resolved?

Comment: `The results work, but I use a mapper to map the results to a view model by going recurisvely through the model.` <= Sounds like an issue with the mapper and not in EF. Could you please post the specifics about this mapper, its configuration, an/or the use of the DTO model?

Comment: @Igor I added my viewmodel mapper implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple solutions:

1) You can use automapper instead of own mapper. It has MaxDepth property which will prevents from this problem:

```cs
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>().MaxDepth(1);
```

2) You can remove dependencies from your entities and use shadow properties in one direction.

Comment: Thanks, I implemented my own simple MaxDepth which solves the problem!

Answer (score 1):

Are you open to changing your data model? I think the best solution would be to remove the circular reference.

If a company contains a list of users, does the User also need both the `CompanyId` and the `Company` object he is contained in? I would remove `public Company Company { get; set; }` from your `CompanyUser` object and `Companies` from your `User` object.

Comment: I suppose I can remove the dependencies in the user yes. They are mostly there because EFCore is not as smart as Entity Framework and cannot always work inverse properties without explicitly defining them.

Comment: This is a common configuration in EF, it is really just a model of a many-to-many relationship. See also https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/many-to-many-relationship-configuration. The issue has nothing to do with the EF model, rather how that data is then mapped to the model(s).

Comment: @Igor Indeed. EF handles them w/o a problem. If some other code (mapping, serialization) cannot handle them correctly, that is their problem and should be fixed there, not in EF model.

Comment: @Igor I know yes, but the result from EF keeps going further down, I suppose I could have created the same example without EF by instantiating the classes by hand and would have had the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you are mapping to `CompanyViewModel` which then maps to `CompanyUserViewModel` but this then maps back again to `CompanyViewModel` which creates an infinite loop.

If you expect to always start at `Company` (to `CompanyView`) then remove the recursion back from `CompanyUserViewModel`.

```
public void ToViewModel(CompanyUser entity)
{
    CompanyId = entity.CompanyId;
    UserId = entity.UserId;
    // Company = entity.Company.ToViewModel<Company, CompanyViewModel>();
    User = entity.User.ToViewModel<User, UserViewModel>();
}
```

Alternatively do not map the relations in your `ToViewModel` mapping, wire up the relations after based on the Ids.